# How to start a new linux session through a linux script- which command would be required to start?

Tags: linux

I want to write a linux shell script that would start a new linux session to carry on application part. Which command should be used... will shell script would be helpful more to carry on this task or there is some other better way.. Please suggest..!!

Comment: what do you mean by "linux session"?

Comment: you need to provide more data. what is a new linux seesion ? what will your script do ? how is it going to be launched (as in from cron, or from the command line interactively) ?

Answer (score 0):

The most convinient way is to run it in backgroud using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html). Use:

```
screen -s session_name
```

to open new session then ctrl-a, ctrl-d to detach session. Any time you can go back to your session by:

```
screen -r session_name
```